# Collapsible JSON content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, jquery-mobile

I'm really new to jQuery and I'm using jQuery mobile 1.4.3 to make an App that has a collapsible to show JSON data.

the JSON data:

```
{
    "ingredients": {
        "sugar": 10,
        "salt": 10,
        "pepper": 10,
        "milk": 10,
        "banana": 10,
        "bacon": 10,
        "olive oil": 10,
        "pork": 10,
        "creams": 10
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't generate the collapsible dynamically from JavaScript.

Here is my attempt:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <ul data-role="listview"  id="listIngredients" data-theme="b"></ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var map = response.ingredients;
$.each(map, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
  $('#listIngredients').append('<li>Title:' + key + value + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: you need to `.listview("refresh")` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vk0ocun2/ and you forgot _header_ for collapsible `<h3>Header</h3>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried adding data-enhanced="true" so code becomes:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-enhanced="true">
    <ul data-role="listview"  id="listIngredients" data-theme="b">
    </ul>
</div>
```